How to initialize an global array to a struct?
Sorry for the bad title, but I don't know how else to phrase why I'm trying to do.
In C, how can I initialize a global array of bytes with a different type?  That is, I'm trying to do this:
#define HEAP_SIZE   2048U

struct memblock
{
    uint16_t prev;
    uint16_t next;
    uint16_t size;
    uint16_t magic;
};

static uint8_t heap[HEAP_SIZE] = (struct memblock)
{
    .prev = 0,
    .next = 0,
    .size = HEAP_SIZE - sizeof(struct memblock),
    .magic = 0,
};

That is, I have a 2048-byte buffer called "heap", and I want to initialize the first 8 bytes according to the layout of memblock.  I know I can write a function to do that, but I want to avoid having to write a function that has to be called in order to initialize this global variable.

I don't think you can do this with static initialization, you should do it in main() using memcpy().

That's what I'm doing now.  I just could have sworn that I've seen this work before.

Why not use a struct that begins with a memblock followed by the heap data? static struct { struct memblock header; data[HEAP_SIZE]; } heap;

Advice: "but I want to..." When you read/hear this expression (or find yourself thinking it), it is time to pause and re-evaluate... This expression is frequently associated with terrible (or disastrous) design/implementation decisions...

As a thought, why not make the array of, say, int64_t? This gives you the ability to effortlessly return properly-aligned addresses in your array, and just as easily casts to a memblock header.

You can do this with a union, although then it requires using the union name to access the array:
static union
{
    uint8_t         heap[HEAP_SIZE];
    struct memblock m;
} u = { .m = {
        .prev = 0,
        .next = 0,
        .size = HEAP_SIZE - sizeof (struct memblock),
        .magic = 0,
    } };

The array would be referred to as u.heap, or you could use a preprocessor macro to conceal the union.
Kludges like this are generally ill advised and should be avoided without good reason.

This is a good answer, though. The only thing that should be directly accessing the heap is the alloc and free functions, and they can totally use the union.member name.

OP has "I want to initialize the first 8 bytes", which this nicely does.  Yet IIRC, the entire 2048 bytes still gets initialized (no partial inits in C).

This is great, thanks.  I won't need to access the union members after init, that's not too kludgy.

You cannot type pun directly, but you can certainly cast:
#define HEAP_SIZE   2048U

struct memblock
{
    uint16_t prev;
    uint16_t next;
    uint16_t size;
    uint16_t magic;
};

static struct memblock heap_[HEAP_SIZE / sizeof(struct memblock) + 1] =
{ {
    .prev = 0,
    .next = 0,
    .size = HEAP_SIZE - sizeof(struct memblock),
    .magic = 0,
} };

static uint8_t * heap = (uint8_t *) heap_;


Nitpick: The ISO C11 standard does not guarantee that uint8_t has "character type" within the meaning of §6.5 ¶7. Therefore, on a platforms on which uint8_t does not have "character type", reading via the pointer heap would violate the strict aliasing rule. Only char, signed char and unsigned char are guaranteed to have "character type". However, I am unaware of any platform on which uint8_t does not have character type.

Doesn't the HEAP_SIZE % sizeof(struct memblock) over-allocate if HEAP_SIZE is not a multiple of sizeof(struct memblock)?  (2048 % 64 == 0, so it doesn't apply to the current values).  Say HEAP_SIZE is 96U and sizeof(struct memblock) is 64.  96 / 64 == 1, but 96 % 64 == 32, so you allocate 32 extra structs when you only need 1 extra.  I think + 1 would always suffice (or a ternary could be used for + 1 or + 0 depending on whether it divided evenly.

@MatthewFlaschen Yes, nice catch. I was still thinking in bytes. Fixed.

Yes, you should struct for this. But syntax to create array of structs is a little different:
struct memblock
{
    uint16_t prev;
    uint16_t next;
    uint16_t size;
    uint16_t magic;
};

static struct memblock heap[HEAP_SIZE] = {
  { // that is a zero element of array
    .prev = 0,
    .next = 0,
    .size = HEAP_SIZE - sizeof(struct memblock),
    .magic = 0,
   },
  { // 1st element
    .prev = 0,
    .next = 0,
    .size = HEAP_SIZE - sizeof(struct memblock),
    .magic = 0,
   },
  {  // 2nd element
    .prev = 0,
    .next = 0,
    .size = HEAP_SIZE - sizeof(struct memblock),
    .magic = 0,
   },
    // and repeat it for HEAP_SIZE times
};

If you do not know how many elements in the array would be, you can do:
static struct memblock heap[] = {
  { ... },
  { ... },
};

And the heap will automatically become array of two elements. And if you need to use that number (for for loop, for example) you will use sizeof:
for (int i=0; i < sizeof(heap)/sizeof(heap[0]); i++) // do something
// or another way to do the same, if you remember what the array contains:
for (int i=0; i < sizeof(heap)/sizeof(struct memblock); i++) // do something


on second thought, if the name heap is really a heap. Then I strongly advise you not do it as a static array. The static array will go into .data segment, and would be stored as is inside your binary. Also, you would need to manually, in source code, adjust all these prev and next members.
It would be much easier and reliable to write an init() function.

The problem is that 'heap' is not an array of these structs.  Only the first 8 bytes is a memblock.  The remain 2040 bytes are uninitialized.

The question says "with a different type"
